# Why the div preview, despite his position is set on relative appears inside the other div?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am gonna to copy paste all the code, so you can check everything and understand what it's the problem. Thank you.

I just wanted to make it appear under the previously div. Just like it shoud be, because this problems not only appears with this div, but with everything else.

```css
.presentazione
{
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}



.sottofondo
{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.messaggio
{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

  border: 1px solid green
}

.sottofondo .icona
{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border:1px solid pink;
}


.preview
{
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="presentazione"> MESSAGE </br> OTHERS THINGS, BLA BLA BLA
  <div class="sottofondo">
    <div class="messaggio"> ANOTHER THING </div>
    <div class="icona"> <img src="Icons/CuoreV.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"/></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="preview"> PROBLEM HERE </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem if I understood correctly is that you have on your `presentazione` element the `top` property which this makes the element to move `100px` from the top of the page without pushing the other elements.

If you want it to have a `100px` distance from top better use `margin-top: 100px`.

I removed the `top` property from that class and it seems to be correct. Check it out below:

```css
.presentazione {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 100px; /* changed from top to margin-top */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.sottofondo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.messaggio {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid green
}

.sottofondo .icona {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="presentazione"> MESSAGE </br> OTHERS THINGS, BLA BLA BLA
  <div class="sottofondo">
    <div class="messaggio"> ANOTHER THING </div>
    <div class="icona"> <img src="Icons/CuoreV.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"/></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="preview"> PROBLEM HERE </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.presentazione` div's position is set to `relative` and its `top:100px`, so other elements are behaving like its still in its original position, therefore you see that overlap, you can try `margin-top:100px` instead of `top:100px` and it will work.
more info on relative positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position